# exibir conteúdo de outra pagina utilizando fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fancybox

Tenho uma página com os nomes de vários produtos e gostaria q ao clicar em um abrisse um fancybox com os detalhes de cada produto. Esses detalhes (nome, preco, etc) estão em outra página e gostaria de exibi-los na mesma página em que estão listados os produtos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tenta isso aqui ^^

scripts js

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.1/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

depois no rodapé

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".fancyboxIframe").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 900,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '90%',
        height      : '90%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
    iframe: {
        scrolling : 'auto',
        preload   : true
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

e no seu html

```
<a href="https://desapegogames.com.br" data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="fancyboxIframe">Clique aqui !!!</a>
```